# React native, tranfrom text to rotate i

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am from to rotate text so it can look like this, but it's not coming in one line like in the image 2, I tried a lot of things to solve it but nothing worked

[image]

I able to rotate it but it's not coming in one line

[image]

I tried a lot of things but still getting same result, below is my code

```
 <FlatList
    data={this.state.coupons}
    keyExtractor={(coupons) => coupons.id.toString()
    renderItem={({item}) => (
        <View style={styles.couponContainer}>
          <View
            style={{
            width: moderateScale(56),
                    backgroundColor: item.colors,
           }}>
           <Text
              style={{
                     ...commonStyles.fontSize16Med,
                      color: colors.white,
                      transform: [{rotate: '270deg'}],
                      marginTop: moderateScaleVertical(20),
                      height: 56,
            }}>
            {strings.DISCOUNT}
            </Text>
            <View style={styles.circle}></View>
            </View>
             <View>
              <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
               <Image
                source={item.icon}
                style={{
                        marginLeft: moderateScale(16),
                        marginTop: moderateScale(16),
                      }}
                />
           <Text
             style={{
                        ...commonStyles.fontsize14,
                        color: colors.blackM,
                        marginLeft: moderateScale(10),
                        marginTop: moderateScaleVertical(20),
                        marginRight: moderateScale(115),
                }}>
                 {item.text}
                </Text>
                  </View>
                  <View
                    style={{
                      flexDirection: 'row',
                      justifyContent: 'space-between',
                    }}>
                    <View>
                      <Text
                        style={{
                          ...commonStyles.fontSize14Med,
                          color: colors.blackM,
                          marginLeft: moderateScale(16),
                          marginTop: moderateScaleVertical(25),
                        }}>
                        {strings.EXPIRES}
                      </Text>
                      <Text
                        style={{
                          ...commonStyles.fontSize14Bold,
                          marginLeft: moderateScale(16),
                          marginTop: moderateScaleVertical(5),
                          marginBottom: moderateScaleVertical(10),
                        }}>
                        {item.expireDate}
                      </Text>
                    </View>
                    <AppButton
                      color={colors.white}
                      title="Redmee"
                      style={{
                        width: moderateScale(100),
                        height: moderateScaleVertical(30),
                        backgroundColor: colors.primary,
                        marginRight: moderateScale(130),
                        marginTop: moderateScaleVertical(30),
                      }}
                      textStyle={commonStyles.fontSize12}
                    />
                  </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.circle2}></View>
              </View>
            )}
          />
```

Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Give width '100%' to your text.

Comment: already tried that didn't worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see the problem is that `Text` is as long as its wrapper (red rectangle). Then you rotate it but it has the same width that's why it's wrapped automatically. You can set the red rectangle's height as width to that Text component.

Comment: As far I understand I according to you I need to set height of red rectangle equal to width of text and It didn't worked

Comment: ya sure, and I will upload my full code so you can check it better, actually it's a card

Comment: You set `height` property to the Text component, you need to set **width** instead.

Comment: And width should be red rectangle's height.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<View
  style={{
    width: moderateScale(56),
    backgroundColor: colors.red,
    transform: [{ rotate: "270deg" }], // add here
  }}
>
  ...
</View>
```